# Сквозное окно или что то подобное

Tags: wpf

Как сделать окно, чтобы при вызове `window.Show()`, оно было бы абсолютно самым верхним и не забирало управления на себя во время появления.

Сейчас происходит так:

1. В момент `window.Show()` окно иногда (не всегда) проваливается под другие клиентские приложения и приходится возвращать его с помощью Alt+Tab
2. В момент `window.Show()` это окно забирает управление на себя. Т.е. если у меня зажата `W` в другом клиентском приложении, то эта `W` как будто отжимается, хотя я не отжимал

   ```
   ResizeMode="NoResize"
   WindowStyle="None"
   AllowsTransparency="True"
   WindowState="Maximized"
   Topmost="True"
   ```

Цель окна, не мешая, показывать уведомления.

Comment: Topmost не работает что ли? Поверх чего вы хотите его отображать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP например поверх игры, которое во всё окно (без рамки). И немного поправил вопрос.

Comment: Наверное для ответа это жирно, пусть будет комментарием...
**WS_EX_TOPMOST + WS_EX_TRANSPARENT + WS_EX_LAYERED + SetLayeredWindowAttributes/LWA_ALPHA** желающий заработать 50 балов может нагуглить по этой строке полное решение на требуемом языке =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков На самом деле, тут достаточно `ShowActivated="False"`

Comment: @Vipz а разве это приведет к тому что мышь при нажатии в это окно будет делать клик "сквозь" окно?

Comment: отображать уведомления поверх полноэкранных DirectX-игр не получится без внедрения своей DLL в процесс игры

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков да, если фон прозрачный, просто забыл его указать.